# Could not deduce (b ~ a)

Tags: haskell

So I have the following code, I'm trying to write an abstract syntax tree for an interpreter, & I prefer not to jam everything in the same `data` type, so I was going to write a typeclass that had the basic behaviour (in this case `AST`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import qualified Data.Map as M

-- ...    

data Expr = forall a. AST a => Expr a
type Env = [M.Map String Expr]

class AST a where
  reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b
  -- when i remove the line below, it compiles fine
  reduce ast _ = ast 

-- ...
```

When I remove the default implementation of `reduce` in the typeclass `AST` it compiles fine, but when ever I provide an implementation that returns it's self it complains. I get the following compiler error

```
src/Data/AbstractSyntaxTree.hs:13:18:
  Could not deduce (b ~ a)
  from the context (AST a)
    bound by the class declaration for `AST'
    at src/Data/AbstractSyntaxTree.hs:(11,1)-(13,20)
  or from (AST b)
    bound by the type signature for reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b
    at src/Data/AbstractSyntaxTree.hs:12:13-36
    `b' is a rigid type variable bound by          
        the type signature for reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b
        at src/Data/AbstractSyntaxTree.hs:12:13
    `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the class declaration for `AST'
        at src/Data/AbstractSyntaxTree.hs:11:11
  In the expression: ast
  In an equation for `reduce': reduce ast _ = ast
```

The behaviour of `AST`'s `reduce` will evaluate an `AST`, and occasionally return a different type of `AST`, and sometimes the same type of `AST`.

### Edit: Regarding `data Expr = forall a. AST a => Expr a` & `GADT`s

I originally went with `data Expr = forall a. AST a => Expr a` because I wanted to represent types like this.

```
(+ 2 true) -> Compound [Expr (Ref "+"), Expr 2, Expr true]

(+ a 2) -> Compound [Expr (Ref "+"), Expr (Ref "a"), Expr 2]

(eval (+ 2 2)) -> Compound [Expr (Ref "eval"), 
                     Compound [
                       Expr (Ref "+"), 
                       Expr 2, 
                       Expr 2]]

((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 2 2) -> Compound [Expr SomeLambdaAST, Expr 2, Expr 2]
```

Since I'm generating ASTs from text I feel it would be a burden to represent a strictly typed ASTs in a GADT, although I do see where they could be useful in case like DSLs in Haskell.

But since I'm generating the AST from text (which could contain some of the examples above), it might be a bit hard to predict what AST I'll end up with. I don't want to start juggling between `Either`s & `Maybe`s. That is what I ended up doing last time & it was a mess, & I gave up trying to attempt this in Haskell.

But again I'm not the most experienced Haskell programmer so maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, maybe I can implement an AST with so more rigours typing, so I'll have a look and see if I can come up with GADTs, but I have my doubts & I have a feeling that it might end the way it did last time.

Ultimately I'm just trying to learn Haskell at the moment with a fun finish able project, so I don't mind if my first Haskell project isn't really idiomatic Haskell. Getting something working is a higher priority just so I can make my way around the language and have something to show for it.

### Update:

I've taken @cdk's & @bheklilr advice and ditched the existential type, although I've gone with a much simpler type, as opposed to utilising GADTs (also suggested by @cdk's & @bheklilr). It could possibly be a stronger type but again I'm just trying to get familiar with Haskell, so I gave up up after a few hours & went with a simple data type like so :P

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Environment = [M.Map String AST]

data AST
  = Compound [AST]
  | FNum Double
  | Func Function
  | Err  String
  | Ref  String

data Function
  = NativeFn ([AST] -> AST)
  | LangFn   [String] AST

-- previously called reduce
eval :: Environment -> AST -> AST
eval env ast = case ast of
  Ref ref -> case (lookup ref env ) of
    Just ast -> ast
    Nothing  -> Err ("Not in scope `" ++ ref ++ "'")

  Compound elements -> case elements of
    []              -> Err "You tried to invoke `()'"
    function : args -> case (eval env function) of
      Func fn -> invoke env fn args
      other   -> Err $ "Cannot invoke " ++ (show other)

  _ -> ast

-- invoke & lookup are defined else where
```

Although I will still probably look at GADTs as they seem to be pretty interesting & have lead me to some interesting reading material regarding implementing abstract syntax trees in haskell.

Comment: I think `a` has to be an AST to... be an AST. I am not sure if that's what you wanted ;)

Comment: I should say I'm pretty inexperienced with Haskell, so I apologise if this question seems pretty simple for more experienced Haskell programmers.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz do you mean like `AST a -> Env -> AST b`

Comment: This is because you're saying that any `AST a` can be directly cast to an `AST b`, which obviously can't be done automatically by the compiler.  If I had `data AST1 = Add Int Int | Mul Int Int` and `data AST2 = Function String [AST2] | Lit Int`, then this definition of `reduce` says that `reduce (Function "subtract" [Lit 1, Lit 2]) some_environment` can be cast directly to an `AST1`, and vice-versa.  How do you picture this would happen?  FYI: The `forall a. AST a => Expr a` is an antipattern in Haskell, I would instead recommend simple ADTs or even GADTs for more complex behavior.

Comment: Continued... So what would `reduce (Function "subtract" [Lit 1, Lit 2]) some_environment :: AST1` be?  How would you encode this for all `AST` types?  This implies that there's a problem with your construction, and you're approaching the problem from too much of an OOP strategy.  Haskell typeclasses are not interfaces, you can't cast from one instance to another.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) page on GADTs for building simple ASTs.  You can pretty easily apply these techniques to much more complex ASTs, but that doesn't mean it's trivial ;)

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr I figured `forall a. AST a => Expr a` would likely not be the most ideal solution :P And you're right about me coming at this from an OOP approach. I'll have a look at GADTs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What part of the error message are you having difficulties understanding? I think it's quite clear.

The type of `reduce` is

```
reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b
```

The first argument has type `a` and GHC expects `reduce` to return something of type `b`, which may be entirely different from `a`. GHC is correct to complain that you've tried to return a value of `a` when it expects `b`.

The "existential quantification with type class" is (as noted by bheklilr) an anti-pattern. A better approach would be to create an Algebraic Data Type for `AST`:

```
data AST a
```

now `reduce` becomes a simple function:

```
reduce :: Env -> AST a -> AST b
```

if you want `reduce` to be able to return a different type of `AST`, you could use `Either`

```
reduce :: Env -> AST a -> Either (AST a) (AST b)
```

but I don't think this is what you really want. My advice is to take a look at the `GADT` style of creating ASTs and re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I interpreted my type signature as it _could be_ another `AST`, I didn't really think it meant I couldn't return the same `AST`.

Comment: Yeah I figure my _existential quantification with type class_ approach might not be the most ideal approach. But consider an `AST` like a number will likely reduce to itself, where as a compound `AST` such as `(my-funciton 2 2)` or `((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 2 2)` to values other than a composite expression, if they have something like `(2 2 2)`, it will be an error in the language. My thinking it could be difficult to represent as a type :/ I mention more of this in my edit.

Comment: I guess your `reduce :: Env -> AST a -> Either (AST a) (AST b)` technically answers the question, but I want avoid cases where I have to match against an Either... But I feel like there should be a more elegant solution

Comment: I agree that adding `Either` or `Maybe` is needlessly complicating things. From your edit it sounds like `GADT`s are _exactly_ what you need. In particular, a recursive type: `data Expr a = Compound [Expr a] | Ref String | Var a`

Comment: Fair enough, I've been reading ASTs seem to be a difficult thing to type, so I guess I'll have to get a little creative :P I'll definitely look into GADTs, I'll update this question after a bit of poking around

Answer (score 1):

You are interpreting this type signature incorrectly (in a way that is common to OO programmers):

```
reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b
```

This does not mean that reduce can choose any type it likes (that is a member of AST) and return a value of that type. If it did, your implementation would be valid. Rather, it means that **for any type b the caller likes** (that is a member of AST), reduce must be able to return a value in that type. b could well be the same as a sometimes, but it's the *caller's* choice, not the choice of reduce.

If your implementation returns a value of type a, then this can only be true if b is always equal to a, which is what the compiler is on about when it reports failing to prove that `b ~ a`.

Haskell does not have subtypes. Type variables are not supertypes of all the concrete types that could instantiate them, as you might be used to using `Object` or abstract interface types in OO languages. Rather type variables are *parameters*; any implementation which claims to have a parametric type must work *regardless* of what types are chosen for the parameters.

If you want to use a design where reduce can return a value in whatever type of AST it feels like (rather than whatever type of AST is asked of it), then you need to use your Expr box again, since Expr is *not* parameterized by the type of AST it contains, but can still contain any AST:

```
reduce :: a -> Env -> Expr
reduce ast _ = Expr ast
```

Now reduce can work regardless of the types chosen for its type parameters, since there's only a. *Consumers* of the returned Expr will have no way of constraining the type inside the Expr, so they'll have to be written to work regardless of what that type is.

Answer (score 0):

Your default implementation doesn't compile, because it has the wrong definition.

```
reduce :: AST b => a -> b -> Env -> b
reduce ast _ = ast
```

Now `ast` has the type `a` and reduce function returns type `b` but according to your implementation you return `ast` which is of type `a` but the compiler expects `b`.

Even something like this will work:

```
reduce :: AST b => a -> b -> Env -> b
reduce _ ast _  = ast
```

Comment: um, did you fail to copy the signature? `reduce :: AST b => a -> Env -> b`

Comment: reduce should only take 2 parameters, am I reading this right?

Comment: @ABot was just showing an case where it will work. :)